# why my doc is not updating in mongodbAtlas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to pull an element from an array in my database(mongoDB) but it's not updating my doc . I used findOneAndUpdate() for purpose I mention above and it finding correct element but it not performing pull method on the element

```
app.post("/delete", async (req, res)=>{

const checkedItem = req.body.deleteItem;
const listName = req.body.listName
```

try{
if(listName === "today"){

```
    await ItemModel.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItem);
    res.redirect("/")
    console.log("successfully deleted");

}else{

        await listModel.findOneAndUpdate({name:listName },
                {$pull: { itemsname: {_id: checkedItem}}},
                {new: true});
                res.redirect("/"+ listName)
            console.log("item deleted from"+listName+checkedItem);

 }}catch(err){console.log(err)}
```

});

this is my model and schema
const itemSchema = {
name: String,
};

const ItemModel = mongoose.model("item", itemSchema);

const listSchema = {
name: String,
itemsname: {
type: Array,
default: [itemSchema]
}
};

const listModel = mongoose.model("list", listSchema);

this is how i am using it.

```
app.get("/:CustomListUrl", async (req, res) => {

const CustomUrl = _.capitalize(req.params.CustomListUrl);

try {
    const find = await listModel.findOne({ name: CustomUrl });

    if (!find) {
        await listModel.create({
            name: CustomUrl,
            itemsname: []
        })
        res.redirect("/" + CustomUrl)
    } else {
        res.render("list", { listtitle: CustomUrl, itemstodo: find.itemsname });
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

});

Comment: Could you provide an example of the model you are trying to update? It is not quite clear from your query whether the `new` is an immediate field of the documents in the `listModel` collection, or a field within a subdocument (like `itemsname._id`).

Comment: const itemSchema = {
    name: String,
};

const ItemModel = mongoose.model("item", itemSchema);

const listSchema = {
    name: String,
    itemsname: {
        type: Array,
        default: [itemSchema]
    }
};
 
this is my two model and schema ;

const listModel = mongoose.model("list", listSchema);
app.get("/:CustomListUrl", async (req, res) => {

Comment: By default, findOneAndUpdate() returns the document as it was before update was applied. You should set the new option to true to return the document after update was applied.